# Make BlockOperation fail so that other dependencies don't execute

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsoperationqueue, nsblockoperation

In a simple case `operation2` is dependent on `operation1`, however `operation1` may fail and in this case we don't want to execute `operation2`

is it possible to deliver a failed execution inside the `operation1` code block? so that `operation1` fails to complete and `operation2` never gets executed and is disposed?

```
let operation1 = BlockOperation {

    // do smth, which can fail

}

let operation2 = BlockOperation {

}


operation2.addDependency(operation1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cancel the dependent operations manually. An `Operation` has a `dependencies` array containing all the operations depending on the operation. In the place in `operation1` that you detect failure, cycle through the `dependencies` array and call `cancel()` on each of the operations in the array.

Calling `cancel()` is not always enough to actually cancel an operation. The general setup is that the beginning of the `start()` function checks the `isCancelled` boolean and if it's `true`, returns without executing the task. So the operation "executes" but doesn't do the actual work. If you've overridden `start()` you will have to do this yourself.

All of this needs to be done before `isFinished` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

`OperationBlock` is a subclass of `Operation` which implements a `cancel()` function and an `isCanceled` property.

If `operation1` fails and wants to stop `operation2` from continuing, it can call the `cancel()` function on the second operation object.

Your code is responsible for checking/polling the `isCanceled` property and taking appropriate action to clean up and stop your operation.